# Sql server 2008 query php

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

```
<?php
    $serverName = "brandobti";
    $usr="sl";
    $pwd="";
    $db="SimpleLabel";

    $connectionInfo = array("UID" => $usr, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database" => $db);

    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if($conn === false)
    {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $sql="update products set Nr_Label=0";

    $query=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    $result=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query);
    print_r($result); 
    sqlsrv_close( $conn);
```

I am trying to figure out exactly what I'm doing wrong in this code.  I know the connection is working correctly; I found a script and tested it.

When I load the PHP page it does nothing at all.

```
<?php
$serverName = "brandobti";
$usr="sl";
$pwd="";
$db="SimpleLabel";

$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $usr, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database" => $db);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($conn === false)

{

print_r( sqlsrv_errors());

}

$sql="Update products set Nr_Labels=0";

$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql) or die(sqlsrv_errors());
$result=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query);
print_r($result); 
sqlsrv_close( $conn);
?>
```

This is the completed and working code for anyone who is having trouble like i was getting sql to connect, thanks marc b for that i been trying to get this working all day long searching forms so i hope anyone else searching can use this

Comment: Is there anything in `sqlsrv_errors`?

Comment: Have you activated and configured `error_reporting` (`E_ALL | E_STRICT`) and `display_errors` (`on`) in your `php.ini`?

Comment: where exactly do i look for this?

Comment: @user1617578 - see Marc B's answer

Comment: @user1617578 Create a new file, for instance `info.php` with the following content: `<?php phpinfo();` - Then point your browser to it. You can fetch your php.ini settings from it and also the location of your php.ini file.

Comment: after turning display errors on i get this Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\testsite\project2\clearlabel.php on line 21

Comment: after adding your line i get this Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlserv_query() in C:\testsite\project2\clearlabel.php on line 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assuming the query succeeded, and don't have any error handling. If there's a problem with any of those DB calls, they generally return false:

```
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql) or die(sqlsrv_errors());
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- add this
```

Comment: after adding your line i get this Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlserv_query() in C:\testsite\project2\clearlabel.php on line 20

Comment: sorry, should be sqlsrv_query.

Comment: sorry marc i should have caught that thanks for the answer i been looking all day for it